# How to lazy load an application by route change

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-ivy

My business request is instead of keeping multiple modules with single application, need to create multiple small applications which can be assigned small team and it should be maintained as separately. so it will run as standalone.

Again, the all small applications need to be used in once of master application which need to deploy in server. I hear about `angular Ivy` - feature. it dynamically load the application too from this video: `[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMPl9wHzmS4&t=1066s][1]` - But I am not able to understand the steps there clearly. as well I could not able to find a tutorial or source by googling.

Any one help me to explain how to pack a small application and import in to master application by lazy loading approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at NX work space. It follows a mono repository structure and it exactly fits for your requirement.
[Nx Extension](https://nx.dev/)

[A value pack for Nx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nstudio/xplat)

Comment: But not find any good tutorial or doc for my requirement, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

As like RajuPedda said, I made a try. But requires more memories and find frame work is heavy. finally I end up here : https://single-spa.js.org/ It does the job!!